# How to give a variable the size of array using size() function in c++?

Tags: c++, arrays, syntax, compiler-errors, c++17

When I write the code it shows error

```
#include <bits/stdc++.h>
using namespace std;
 
int main()
{
    int arr[] = {12, 3, 4, 15};
    int n = arr.size();
    
    cout << "Size of array is " << n;
    return 0;
}




Compilation failed due to following error(s).
main.cpp:7:17: error: request for member ‘size’ in ‘arr’, which is of non-class type ‘int [4]’

    7 |     int n = arr.size();
      |                 ^~~~
```

it also didn't work for vector array i tried that also can't understand the problem

Comment: Use a `std::vector<int>` instead of a raw array.

Comment: You can also use `sizeof(arr)/sizeof(arr[0])` or the non standard `_countof(arr)` which exists on some platforms.

Comment: _"it also didn't work for vector array"_: what is a vector array?

Comment: `#include <bits/stdc++.h>` -- I know you didn't get this from a reputable C++ book, which you should be using to learn C++.  Instead, you probably got code from a dodgy C++ website and [used this non-standard header](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31816095/why-should-i-not-include-bits-stdc-h).

Answer (score 6):

As a rule of thumb, use

```
std::vector<int> arr = {12, 3, 4, 15};
```

with

```
arr.size();
```

returning the number of elements, unless you have a good reason not to.

Failing that, `std::size(arr)` will give you the number of elements, but only if `arr` has not already decayed to a pointer type by virtue of your receiving it as a function parameter. That C++ standard library function does something clever to obviate the normal pointer decay you observe with C-style arrays.

Answer (score 5):

C-array doesn't have methods.

Since C++17, you might use [`std::size`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/iterator/size):

```
const auto n = std::size(arr);
```

Comment: `int` for the type. Really?

Comment: @Bathsheba Why is that problematic?

Comment: @PasserBy `int` can be as small as [-32767, 32767] (C++20 gives you an extra negative) and vulnerable to overflow.

Comment: @Bathsheba: I used `int` as OP. Changed to `auto`.